# Java Script select a value in an array between two set numbers

Tags: javascript, html

Okay i know what i want but i don't know how to do it. I know there's gotta be a solution, but i don't know how to find it or what to search so im gonna ask the best i can:

I have an array:

```
    var array = ['dud', 'bang', 'bang2', 'bang3'];
```

A simple array. 
I know how to select a value from an array and show it through an alert:

```
    var item = array[0];  // my variable equal to a value in my array
    array(item);  //Shows item variable
```

Now i wanna make a math equation where JavaScript randomly selects a number between 0 - 3 rounded:

```
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
```

Now if i place this in a variable:
        var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

Can i put this value in my array selector?:

```
    array[result];
```

Would this work? If not, how would i go about this? I've tried using this before:

```
    array[getRandomInt(0, 3)];
```

But i don't know how to get the value and display it using alert or to use the result as a value. If that makes sense.

I want to be able to make a function where it selects a random value from an array every time it is run. I also would like it to be choosing random values from the array between 0 - 3 then 4 - 5 or even 10 - 11 (Sort of like categories). This value would substitute into a global variable for me to use in like for say a sentence:

```
    var array = ['dud', 'bang', 'bang2', 'bang3'];
    var selector = whatever it may be to get a random value from 'array'

    document.getElementById.(MyParagraph) = "\"I counted to the number\" + selector"
```

Hopefully i described my problem/question the best i can. If there already is a solution, please send me a link to it. If it cant be done, just let me know.

Comment: "*Would this work?*" - I mean...did you try?

Comment: Would what work? I tried exactly what ive said. Ive asked before but never got a full answer.

Comment: I was quoting your question. Specifically, the part where you ask whether `array[result];` would work. Yes, that would work. It returns the value at the index in the array. You can assign that value to a variable like any other value.

Comment: Yes it does work, but once i put things like Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); it wont work. I dont know if im typing it wrong or what.

Comment: I particularly want it to be random and not a set number.

Comment: Sure works for me: `var randomElement = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]; alert(randomElement);`

Comment: what does array.length do? im sorry, still knew to some of these JavaScript syntax's.

Comment: And yea i got this working just now actually:         function math() {
    var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
    alert(array[result]);
}

Comment: btw, `document.getElementById` is a method, so no dot after the method name for calling.

Comment: thanks Nina Scholz, will keep in mind.

Comment: `array.length` gets the number of elements in the array. I suggest you check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length?v=control).

Comment: Alright, now this is working for me, but what if i want to select random values in an array from between 2 - 3 or 11 - 12?

Comment: are you sure about `array(item);` in the second line? That should be an error.

Comment: woops should have been 'alert', my bad.